# Is this video of harassment in an elevator staged?

Tags: china, video

The Huffington Post has reported on a video showing a man sexually harassing a woman and then getting beat up by her: http://m.huffpost.com/au/entry/9792076

It looks fake. For example the harasser tries to grab her breast by reaching over her shoulder rather than reaching around her, which doesn't seem practical, and it seems strange for an incident to have been noticed by the owner of the closed circuit TV footage (not to mention being leaked to the internet, and also reaching English-language media in a couple of days), unless one of the two reported the incident.

Is this video genuine, or is it staged?

Comment: I don't know. Looks real enough to me. That initial slap is pretty convincing. The other blows as well, upon review.

Comment: Would there be any way to prove authenticity? The way I see it, this question can be answered only in one case — there is evidence that this is staged.

Comment: @vartec the media contacting those involved or the owner of the footage I guess.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is that media _not_ confirming that with the involved is _not_ enough to say that it's staged.

Comment: @vartec checking if it's staged could involve finding out who posted the video and seeing if they had form for staged videos.

Comment: I like how the huffington post just assumes it's not staged, that they didn't have any history and that sending a man to the hospital for being creepy deserves an applause instead of an arrest...

Comment: Maybe it deserves applause and an arrest.